# Version 2.3.1 not always shows the boxes when layout getOrgChart.MIXED_HIERARCHY_RIGHT_LINKS?

Tags: getorgchart

I´m using getOrgChart version 2.3.1 free version and I´m facing the problem that not always is rendering the boxes when layout is layout as getOrgChart.MIXED_HIERARCHY_RIGHT_LINKS.

If I switch to grid view, the nodes appear but in the main view there are no boxes. There are no errors, and sometimes the boxes appears but sometimes not.

I noticed that if I remove the layout as getOrgChart.MIXED_HIERARCHY_RIGHT_LINKS
the boxes always appear.

Is something with the free version?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check again your `dataSource` supply make sure there is no single node, apparently `getOrgChart.MIXED_HIERARCHY_RIGHT_LINKS` cannot draw single node